# How do i mock the ApplicationRunner bean, so that ApplicationContext gets loaded with this mocked ApplicationRunner Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have an ApplicationRunner bean which executes some flyway migrations.

```
@Bean
ApplicationRunner flywayRunner(){
    return new ApplicationRunner() {
        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
            Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname").load(); 
            flyway.migrate();
        }
    };
}
```

I have not written any test cases yet, but some already existing Integration test cases are failing because of unable to load ApplicationContext with the bean ApplicationRunner.

I am kind of a newbie to spring, so not sure how i can make the existing test cases pass.

Comment: Why do you have this runner? Spring Boot supports flyway out-of-the-box and you don't need this runner at all. You can then simply disable flyway in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation in your integration test classes to create or start up an application context for your test cases.For tests that cover the whole Spring Boot application from incoming request to database, or tests that cover certain parts of the application that are hard to set up manually, we can and should use `@SpringBootTest`. We can use annoations like `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to customize the configurations and mock beans being loaded into the application context.You could even provide your own custom main application class for running integration test cases and use it to load your own configurations for the tests :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = CustomApplication.class)
class CustomApplicationTest {

}
```

If you just want to add one Bean you could also use the `@Import` annotation to import the required bean.